# In which directory should I save my .dat file?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am currently writing a very simple script on python which requires that I download a .dat file posted online.  I then use loadtxt to plot the data using matplotlib.  However, in order to read the file, I had to change directory (os.chdir) to 'downloads' (where the file had been saved).  This works fine for me, but I will need to send the script to somebody else, in which case it seems as though the directory would again need to be something else in order to find the file...  Where might I save the file so that no matter to whom I send it, the script will run properly?

Comment: Which operating system?  Why not create a specific directory for the task and use that?

Comment: does not matter where you save it if the user moves it, there is no magic location so just keep it in the same directory as the script.

Answer (score 0):

User-specific path to the dat file can be acquired using:

```
os.chdir(raw_input('Which is the path to the download folder?'))
```